# Как вызвать заставку Windows и поменять цвет?

Tags: java, windows

Задача, через Java поменять цвет монитора на конкретно заданный. Допустим, красный.

Я так понял, что необходимо вызвать заставку Windows (изначально черный) и затем поменять цвет, но я не знаю какой командой это можно сделать.

Есть команда

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"scrnsave.scr","/s","start"});}
```

Которая вызывает черный экран (Заставка видимо)

Если эта верная команда, то как сделать, чтобы эта заставка была красной?

Comment: может быть проще окно самой программы в [полноэкранном режиме](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11570600) показывать?

Comment: я не уверен. Вы думаете лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно создать JFrame на весь экран, сделать ему setUndecorate(true), залить его нужным вам цветом, ну и сделать setAlwaysOnTop(true). Затем, подключить к нему обработчик событий движения мыши и по наступлению оного - закрывать фрейм.

Comment: Задание такое, к сожалению) Необходимо сделать.

Однако для линукса также актуально, но сначала для винды надо

Comment: @cheops поправил